# How to click in a div?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, google-chrome-headless

I'm trying to perform a click on different div class TopBox. i tried the codes below but i don't get the click performed : 
[image: Snapshot]

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#home > div > div.row.topBoxs > div.col-xs-12.col-lg-10 > div > div:nth-child(1) > div').click()
```

and also :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="home"]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]').click()
```

Below is the snapshot of the code of the box "mes posts" as exemple and the other boxes.
[image: Mes Posts HTML code]
[image: HTML code :]

Comment: Is it possible to show us the url of the page?

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `xpath` instead of `css_selector`.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath_of_your_Div').click()
```

Comment: Which website/page is it?

Comment: it's a private website

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you have to do.

```
# get number of the toolboxes first
toolBoxes = len(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.boxs div[class^='topBox ']"))

# now you can click on each of them
for boxNumber in range(toolBoxes):
    # you can use either xpath/css to get the nth box and click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@class='boxs']/div[starts-with(@class,'topBox ')])[" + str(boxNumber+1) + "]").click()
    # waiting here so that you can see the element is clicked (optional)
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: i get this error `raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"div.boxes div[class^='topBox `]"}`

Comment: Try with the updated answer. I mentioned "\`" instead of `'` that's why you got the error.

Comment: i've tried that before but i'm getting the same error `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"div.boxes div[class^='topBox ']"}`

Comment: Can you try the `div.boxs div[class^='topBox ']` css in chrome devtools if the element is located. Corrected the class name from `boxes` to `boxs`.

Comment: Please post the html code from your next question so that we don't hit this typos's :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code with this css selector:

```
all_boxes = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.content-box span")

for box_i in range(len(all_boxes)):
    driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.content-box span")[box_i].click()
```

If you are getting an error, please let me know, what it is.

Comment: thanks for you help.. i got this error `driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.boxs > div.topBox > div.content-box")[box_i].click()
TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: @AbdoRabah  please try again, I just updated my answer above... looks promising though :)

Comment: the result of `len(all_boxes)` is equal to 1.. and even if i perform the click it's not doing anything

Comment: Weird, let's remove the anchor to the top one. Fixed the answer. How about now? @AbdoRabah

Comment: i still have the same result as before

Comment: Edited again, another locator, but this is strange, I can definitely see 4 ones with this locator on your screenshot. Can you maybe add `time.sleep(3)` before searching for `all_boxes`, I wonder if it just takes too long for them all to load.

Comment: I see that too but i don't think that's the problem..if you see the first pictures `"Mes posts"` corresponds with the code that is in the section `<div class= "topBox filt-box">..</div>`and the others `Signalement`, `Vote` and `ìnformation` to `<div class= "topBox filt-box ng-start-inserted">..</div>`

Answer (score 0):

1. Firstly, check if you are able to locate the element. If it is not then following line should be throwing error:

   ```
   WebElement theButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class='boxs']/div[1]/div');
   ```

alternatively pls try this xpath as well

```
    '//div[@class='boxs']/div[1]/div/div/p/span'
```

2. Wait for the element till its clickable

   ```
   wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
   wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, my_xpath)))
   ```
3. Then try clicking the element with .click()

Please let me know your observations which would help troubleshoot